# Oh my zsh is only working when i log in as root

Tags: debian, zsh, oh-my-zsh, alacritty

Recently installed zsh and oh my zsh but when i open a terminal nothing changes, the bar keeps looking as always but it changes only when i log as root doing sudo su, I have tried almost everyting but nothing changed.

I am using alacritty.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you installed it for root, not your own user.

Read Documentation: [Installing OH-MY-ZSH](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki).

Troubleshooting steps:

**1. Are your user (not root) using ZSH really? In your user:**

```bash
% echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

If not, `chsh -s $(which zsh)` **NO SUDO**!

**2. Install Oh-My-Zsh without SUDO**

```bash
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)
```

OR

```bash
sh -c "$(wget -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

OR

```bash
sh -c "$(fetch -o - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Comment: I don't know why but it only worked with the wget one, i was trying wiht curl, but finally worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Unlucko, could you up vote my answer? I need reputation here. I will up vote your question.

Comment: As soon as i get to 15 reputation i will upvote your answer.